# Including file in head using PHP string replace

Tags: php, html, head

I am trying to include a `head.php` file in `index.php` using PHP string replace.

My Code (index.php) :

```
$headin = include "head.php";

$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
        )
    )
);

$homepage = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/", false, $context);
$homepage = str_replace("<head>", "<head>". $headin, $homepage);
echo $homepage;
```

The problem is, the content of `head.php` displaying above the `<html>` instead of displaying inside `<head>`.

Comment: are you sure that $homepage <head> is not above in html ?

Comment: That's not how `include` works, it doesn't return the contents into a string - check the documentation

Comment: @Jerson yes the content of `head.php` displaying above `<head>` tag

Comment: @ADyson can you tell me how to include the content of `head.php` in between `<head>` tag

Comment: `$headin` will be either TRUE or FALSE as that is what `include` returns [PHP Manual - See example 5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) Also take a look at [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents) as that may be more appropriate

Comment: you may use output buffering to get the string from your include

Comment: @RiggsFolly i checked the manual and still confused how one can include the file between string :(

Comment: `$headin = file_get_contents('head.php');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i think if you include that also if the head has php syntax then it will include on the str_replace not good idea? rather

Comment: @Jerson You make a good point, I think we need to know more about what is in `head.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly my mistake. your suggestion work. Thanks you for helping me resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal to reuse page components - there are many possibilities ...

## require_once

You can use `require_once` to include the content

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <?php require_once 'head.php'; ?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**head.php**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?= basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.php') ?></title>
</head>
```

## RewriteRule

Another approach would be to use a rewrite rule that routes all traffic through **index.php** and then include the relevant content

```
<Directory "/">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Test it out with

**index.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

## pre/post pend

You can also use Apache to add head and tail content

```
<Directory "/">
php_value auto_prepend_file head.php
php_value auto_append_file tail.php
</Directory>
```

**head.php**

This could include navigation

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?= basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],'.php') ?></title>
</head>
<body>
```

**tail.php**

This could include a page footer.

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

Using of `file_get_contents` instead of `include`.

My problem got fixed by replace my code from `$headin = include "head.php";` to `$headin = file_get_contents('head.php');`

Thanks to @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

If file head.php is echoing some thing , then the content of that file will be echoed as soon as it is included . so you can either shift the content in head.php into a function and call that function inside this file

If moving content to function is not possible then you can use php's output buffering
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php